# Splitting all characters in a string into an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, python-2.7, character

Is there any way to split a string such as `'00:00'` into an array such as `['0', '0, ':' , '0', '0']` ? I have tried:

```
time = raw_input()
digital = time.split()
```

where time is the input string `'00:00'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to split, you can simply use `list(..)`:

```
digital = list(time)
```

A string is a *iterable*: you can iterate over the characters. The `list(..)` constructor takes as input an iterable, and constructs a list where each element of the iterable (the characters in this case), is an element of the list.

For example:

```
>>> time = raw_input()
00:00
>>> list(time)
['0', '0', ':', '0', '0']
```